# Print timezone of server

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I need show the timezone of server, example GMT-03:00, how I can make this in Java?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.error(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));        
}
```

Comment: You posted some code. Does it or doesn't it work? Tell us what it does, if not what you expect

Comment: GMT-03:00 isn't really the time zone - that's just the offset, which may change over time. Look at `TimeZone.getDefault()`

Comment: I don't see any R content here.

Comment: I need print the TimeZone, example -03:00, I make various test and print sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Sao_Paulo",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=129,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Sao_Paulo,offset=-10800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=9,startDay=15,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=0,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=1,endDay=15,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=0,endTimeMode=0]]

Comment: Is this running on the server? I'm confused as to why you are getting the timezone for America/Sao_Paulo rather than the local system default.

Comment: `-10800000 = -03:00` .., see [`TimeZone` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

Comment: I try this logger.error(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo").getRawOffset()/(60*60*1000));

Comment: but in my country have sun time -02:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend **Joda-Time** library for work with time in Java. It's much better than default realization.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ZZ");
System.out.println("GMT "+dateTimeFormatter.withZone(zone).print(0) +" for "+zone.toString());
```

will print `GMT -03:00 for America/Sao_Paulo`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` to get a similar result:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("z XXX");
System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

The javadoc is available [in this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X'
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:696)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:515)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:464)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:445)
 at

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("z XXX");
System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));

Comment: What JVM are you using? What version is it?

Comment: The pattern 'X' only works on Java 7. If you are using Java 6, see [this javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Try `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("z ZZZ");` It produces a similar result.